Ambigious clock in event control
I want to generate a slow clock from input clock which is clk_in, but it shows the following error:

ambigious clock in event control

module clk_div_h(rst, clk_in, clk_div);

input rst, clk_in;
output reg clk_div = 0;
reg [3:0]clk_count = 0;

always @(posedge clk_in or posedge rst)
begin
    clk_count <= clk_count + 1;
    clk_div <= clk_count[3];
end

endmodule

How can I resolve the error? I am using nexys 4 DDR FPGA.

Who is showing that error?

What is rst for? It's not used.

The error message means that your code does not follow one of the synthesis constructs supported by your synthesis tool.
You are attempting to describe D flip-flop behavior with your Verilog code, but your synthesis software does not recognize the code pattern as any of the flip flops it supports.  A flop requires one clock input signal to be in the Verilog sensitivity list:
always @(posedge clk_in or posedge rst)

The problem with your list is that includes 2 signals (clk_in and rst), but it is ambiguous to the synthesis tool which signal should be the clock input.  The name of the signal is irrelevant.  The order of the signals is also irrelevant.
One way to avoid this error is to remove the rst signal:
always @(posedge clk_in)

The synthesis tool will infer flip flops with clk_in as the clock input.  In this case, I don't think there is any need for the rst module input.
However, if you do want to keep the rst module input, then you can also keep your original sensitivity list, but you need to add an if/else statement to your code:
module clk_div_h(rst, clk_in, clk_div);

input rst, clk_in;
output reg clk_div;
reg [3:0] clk_count;

always @(posedge clk_in or posedge rst)
begin
    if (rst) begin
        clk_count <= 0;
        clk_div   <= 0;
    end else begin
        clk_count <= clk_count + 1;
        clk_div   <= clk_count[3];
    end
end

endmodule

This should eliminate the error message because there is no longer any ambiguity.  It should infer flip flops with an asynchronous reset, with rst as the reset signal since it is used in the body of the always block.
Note that I also removes the initializations from your reg declarations.  The benefit to this code style is that it is also portable to ASIC design flows (not just FPGA flows).
